# How to Use Configuration with ValidateDataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've read the Microsoft documentation of fundamentals for [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but still can't find the right way to extract configuration into an object while validating data annotations.

One approach I tried in `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddOptions<EmailConfig>().Bind(Configuration.GetSection("Email")).ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

This "should" allow accessing the configuration by adding this in the class constructor: `(IOptions<EmailConfig> emailConfig)`

However it's not working.

Another approach is to add `(IConfiguration configuration)` to the constructor, but this doesn't allow me to call `ValidateDataAnnotations`.

```
configuration.GetSection("Email").Get<EmailConfig>();
```

First question: does the responsibility to bind and validate the configuration belong to the Startup class or to the class using it? If it's used by several classes I'd say it belongs to Startup; and the class could be used in another project with different configuration layout.

Second question: what is the correct syntax to bind and validate the configuration so it can be accessed from the class?

Third question: if I'm validating through data annotations in Startup, then the class using the configuration simply assumes the configuration is valid and I don't put any re-validation whatsoever?

**UPDATE: After gaining more experience and reviewing the structure of all my code, I changed my approach to follow standard patterns.**

The following code DOES work... but only validates it when used. This can be registered in a class library and won't throw any errors until the particular service is used.

```
services.AddOptions<EmailConfig>()
    .Bind(configuration.GetSection("Email"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

Then, in Configure, I add this to force validation of needed configuration values at startup (CheckNotNull is a custom extension method, what matters is simply that you call IOptions.Value

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app?.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<EmailConfig>>().Value.CheckNotNull("Config: Email");
    app?.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<OntraportConfig>>().Value.CheckNotNull("Config: Ontraport");
    ...
```

Then in the class using it

```
public class EmailService(IOptions<EmailConfig> config)
```

Comment: IOptions classes can have a 'post' load class that can be used to validation.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options  In answer to your 3rd question, validation shouldn't be part of the class that uses the config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try validating the class yourself in start up before adding it to service collection.

*Startup*

```
var settings = Configuration.GetSection("Email").Get<EmailConfig>();

//validate
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(settings, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(settings, validationContext, validationResults, 
        validateAllProperties: true)) {
    //...Fail early
    //will have the validation results in the list
}

services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

That way you are not coupled to `IOptions` and you also allow your code to fail early and you can explicitly inject the dependency where needed.

You could package the validation up into your own extension method like

```
public static T GetValid<T>(this IConfiguration configuration) {
    var obj = configuration.Get<T>();    
    //validate
     Validator.ValidateObject(obj, new ValidationContext(obj), true);    
    return obj;
}
```

for calls like

```
EmailConfig emailSection = Configuration.GetSection("Email").GetValid<EmailConfig>();
services.AddSingleton(emailSection);
```

Internally, [`ValidateDataAnnotations`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/cc317e6112479d36ba77a57e1eeea5d88a164a6c/src/Options/DataAnnotations/src/OptionsBuilderDataAnnotationsExtensions.cs#L19) is basically doing the same thing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Validates a specific named options instance (or all when name is null).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The name of the options instance being validated.</param>
/// <param name="options">The options instance.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="ValidateOptionsResult"/> result.</returns>
public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, TOptions options)
{
    // Null name is used to configure all named options.
    if (Name == null || name == Name)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Validator.TryValidateObject(options,
            new ValidationContext(options, serviceProvider: null, items: null), 
            validationResults, 
            validateAllProperties: true))
        {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            validationResults.Select(r => "DataAnnotation validation failed for members " +
                String.Join(", ", r.MemberNames) +
                " with the error '" + r.ErrorMessage + "'.")));
    }

    // Ignored if not validating this instance.
    return ValidateOptionsResult.Skip;
}
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/cc317e6112479d36ba77a57e1eeea5d88a164a6c/src/Options/DataAnnotations/src/DataAnnotationValidateOptions.cs#L31)

Comment: I like the idea of decoupling IOptions, and it's good to learn how to trigger validation manually. However, my library Websites.Business will contain various sections such as "email sending" and "payment processing" used by several websites. One website will use both while another will only need "email sending", so validating on use might be better in that case. Also, you're not answering the question: how to use ValidateDataAnnotations. Then "fail early" will probably be added in Core 3.0

Comment: Oh, parsing/validating config sections belongs to each website so that would work. Still, I would like to know how ValidateDataAnnotations is used. The whole validation block of code you wrote could easily be put into a generic helper function -- there's no such one-line method already doing it?

Answer (score 11):

### Update from the Future

Newer versions of .NET added more extension methods to simplify this.

Note: Technically these are all from `Microsoft.Extensions.XYZ` packages released alongside .NET. It's possible that these packages are compatible with earlier versions of .NET as well, but I haven't verified backward-compatibility.

### OP's Example

```cs
services.AddOptions<EmailConfig>()
    .Bind(configuration.GetSection("Email"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

Can now be simplified to:

```cs
// Requires .NET 5 extensions or greater
services.AddOptions<EmailConfig>()
    .BindConfiguration("Email")
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

...and for eager validation at startup (rather than when options are used), we can add a single line:

```cs
// Requires .NET 6 extensions or greater
services.AddOptions<EmailConfig>()
    .BindConfiguration("Email")
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

### Source/Credit

I learned about these updates from Andrew Lock's blog post. Credit and thanks go to him: [Adding validation to strongly typed configuration objects in .NET 6](https://andrewlock.net/adding-validation-to-strongly-typed-configuration-objects-in-dotnet-6/)

Comment: Now that is useful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is still no answer as to how ValidateDataAnnotations work, but based on Nkosi's answer, I wrote this class extension to easily run the validation on-demand. Because it's an extension on Object, I put it into a sub-namespace to only enable it when needed.

```
namespace Websites.Business.Validation {
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides methods to validate objects based on DataAnnotations.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ValidationExtensions {
        /// <summary>
        /// Validates an object based on its DataAnnotations and throws an exception if the object is not valid.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to validate.</param>
        public static T ValidateAndThrow<T>(this T obj) {
            Validator.ValidateObject(obj, new ValidationContext(obj), true);
            return obj;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates an object based on its DataAnnotations and returns a list of validation errors.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to validate.</param>
        /// <returns>A list of validation errors.</returns>
        public static ICollection<ValidationResult> Validate<T>(this T obj) {
            var Results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var Context = new ValidationContext(obj);
            if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, Context, Results, true))
                return Results;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Startup it's quite straightforward

```
EmailConfig EmailSection = Configuration.GetSection("Email").Get<EmailConfig>().ValidateAndThrow();
services.AddSingleton<EmailConfig>(EmailSection);
```

Works like a charm; actually works like I'd expect ValidateDataAnnotations to work.

Comment: Have a look at the example extension I added to my answer

Comment: Ah I like your GetValid, it makes an extension only on IConfiguration instead of all objects which is a lot better for Intellisense. To throw an exception on failure, however, you can do it in a single line instead of using the long syntax that returns the list of errors.

Comment: Yeah I made that change already. Really simplifies the function

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a method to validate all IOptions in your IOC conainter

```
private void CheckConfiguration(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var optionsServiceDescriptors = services.Where(s => s.ServiceType.Name.Contains("IOptionsChangeTokenSource"));

        foreach (var service in optionsServiceDescriptors)
        {
            var genericTypes = service.ServiceType.GenericTypeArguments;

            if (genericTypes.Length > 0)
            {
                var optionsType = genericTypes[0];
                var genericOptions = typeof(IOptions<>).MakeGenericType(optionsType);

                dynamic instance = app.ApplicationServices.GetService(genericOptions);
                var options = instance.Value;
                var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
               
                var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(options, new ValidationContext(options), results, true);
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    var messages = new List<string> { "Configuration issues" };
                    messages.AddRange(results.Select(r => r.ErrorMessage));
                    throw new Exception(string.Join("\n", messages));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can find a example here : https://github.com/michelcedric/GetRequiredSectionSample/blob/feature/add-check-configuration/GetRequiredSectionSample/Startup.cs#L73