# Model validation for configuration objects in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In .NET Core, if my appsettings file looks like

```
{
  "Section": {
    "Field": "value"
  }
}
```

I can create a class like

```
public class Section
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

and retrieve the value in Startup like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.Configure<Section>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Section"));
}
```

The problem is that if for some reason (say misspelling) the binding fails, it is not going to throw, and instead it will create a `Section` object with null (default) value for the `Field` property.

Is there a way to make `services.Configure<Section>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Section"));` to throw if the binding fails?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025264/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi that was neat! summed up your answer here in the hope it saves some time for the next reader, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just summing up @Nkosi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025264/5233410) which makes this validation possible using data annotation.

1- Annotate the properties of your class:

```
public class Section
{
    [Required]
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

2- Create an extension method to enable validation to take effect:

```
public static class ConfigurationModelValidation
{
    public static T GetValid<T>(this IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var obj = configuration.Get<T>();
        Validator.ValidateObject(obj, new ValidationContext(obj), true);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

3- In the `Startup` class, register you configuration models as below using `GetValid` method (instead of using 'IOptions'):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddSingleton(this.Configuration.GetSection("Section").GetValid<Section>());
}
```

4- Now in the user's class directly inject your configuration model:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly string field;

    public MyClass(Section section)
    {
        this.field = section.field;
    }
}
```

Now if binding fails for any reason, the validation will kick in and it will throw, enjoy!

Comment: Yep that is more or less the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the section first, then verify it exists (because it will not be `null`).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    var section = this.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Section));
    if (!section.Exists()) throw new Exception();
    services.Configure<Section>(section);
}
```