# IOptions Validation doesn't fire until I call validate method with property explicitly in Asp.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, startup, appsettings

Recently i was using IOptions interface to read configuration in Asp.net core project and i found that my code doesn't show exception page until i call "validate" method explicitly with required property as you can see in below code.

appsettings.json

```
"DashboardSettings": {
"Header": {
  "Title": "Seguro De Coche"//,
  //"SearchBoxEnabled": true
}
```

},

DashboardSetting.cs

```
public class DashboardSettings
{
    public HeaderSettings Header { get; set; }
}
public class HeaderSettings
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool SearchEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddOptions<DashboardSettings>().
            Bind(configuration.GetSection("DashboardSettings")).
            ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

In above case, "SearchEnabled" property required validation doesn't fire. and when i call validate methods explicitly with property, it fires. (see code below with validation method)

```
services.AddOptions<DashboardSettings>().
         Bind(configuration.GetSection("DashboardSettings")).
            ValidateDataAnnotations().
            Validate(v =>
            {
                return v.Header.SearchEnabled;
            });
```

[image: options-validation-in-aspnet-core]

so my question is, if my strongly type would have multiple configuration properties, then would i use all properties of class for validating them? If it is, it doesn't seem a good idea to me. Any suggestion on this please?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025264/5233410

Comment: why not use FluentValidation? https://fluentvalidation.net/

Comment: @Nkosi Decoupling IOptions and validating them that way is a good idea you explained, but i just wanted to know why only "ValidateDataAnnotations" calling didn't work for me? Implementing IValidateOptions always a good idea for complex validations.

Comment: What is your DataReadService?

Comment: @Rena its just a singleton service which is using my DashboardSettings options via constructor injection. that's why its displaying error in that file on validation failed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was an option back in .net core 3 but in .net core 6 you have to call

```
.ValidateOnStart()
```

on the optionsbuilder returned from AddOptions<>()

Otherwise, validation is called when the object is retrieved for the first time.

Comment: it wasn't, it's introduced only in 6

Comment: are you sure? im using aspnetcore 7 and i can't find it

Answer (score 0):

`ValidateDataAnnotations` method are not called until the `IOptions` is actually resolved, meaning you request the `Value` property of it. It is not enough even for DI to resolve the IOption for you. This validation is simply 'very lazy'

If you want this validation to happen earlier and you use ASP.NET Core 6, you can now add ValidateOnStart method.

If you need to use one of the previous version or want more control over the error handling, you can simply ensure that your IOptions are resolved earlier in the process, e.g. during Service Configuration.

To do that create a class, that depends on those options, and make it request their values. Add its instance in Startup.cs:

```
    public class ConfigurationValidator ( IOptions<MyConfig> MyConfig )
    {
        //no validation trigger yet
        MyConfig = myConfig;
    }

    public IOptions<MyConfig> MyConfig { get; }

    internal void Validate()
    {
        //validation happens in this line:
        _ = MyConfig?.Value;
    }
```

And now in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ConfigurationValidator configValidator)
{
      try
      {
            configValidator.Validate();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      { 
           //log your errors 
      }
      //process continues here, or not...
}
```

This approach leaves full control to you so you can decide how to handle your error. But in fact you don't need the `Validate` method, as the whole logic can happen already in constructor and then `Configure` method will immediately stop the process and rethrow exception

Ahh, and of course you need to register your ConfigurationValidator as a service. Singleton or whatever.