# How to trigger model validation inside IValidateOptions<T> implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have a .Net 5 app and want to add validators for my configurations. Given this sample options

```
public sealed class DatabaseOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

I currently validate it with this implementation

```
public sealed class DatabaseOptionsValidator : IValidateOptions<DatabaseOptions>
{
    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, DatabaseOptions databaseOptions)
    {
        List<string> validationFailures = new List<string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseOptions.ConnectionString))
            validationFailures.Add($"{nameof(databaseOptions.ConnectionString)} is required.");

        // ...

        if (validationFailures.Any())
        {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validationFailures);
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid implementing my own validation checks and error messages since I know data annotations already get the job done.

I modified the options model to this

```
public sealed class DatabaseOptions
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(9999999)] // for testing purposes
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

and was hoping to find a way to trigger the model validation

```
public sealed class DatabaseOptionsValidator : IValidateOptions<DatabaseOptions>
{
    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, DatabaseOptions databaseOptions)
    {
        List<string> validationFailures = new List<string>();

        // trigger the model validation and add every error to the validationFailures list

        if (validationFailures.Any())
        {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validationFailures);
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
}
```

but unfortunately I wasn't able to do so. The debugger hits the validator but how can I trigger the validation inside the Validate method?

Comment: Can you not just use the DataAnnotations validator via `ValidateDataAnnotations`? See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/55025197/491907. Not quite a duplicate, but the question itself shows an example and the answer shows how the data annotations validator actually works internally so you could copy that implementation if necessary. It's actually fairly basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a technique I use for validating data annotations in my netcore apps, not using `IValidateOptions`, but implementing a custom validator, and registering it as `PostConfigure`.

You can find valuable assets in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Something like this:

```
    // Custom validator for data annotations
    public static class Validation {
        public static void ValidateDataAnotations<TOptions>(TOptions options) {
            var context = new ValidationContext(options);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(options, context, results, validateAllProperties: true);
            if (results.Any()) {
                var aggrErrors = string.Join(' ', results.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
                var count = results.Count;
                var configType = typeof(TOptions).Name;
                throw new ApplicationException($"Found {count} configuration error(s) in {configType}: {aggrErrors}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, you register this static method in you composition root (probably `Startup.cs`):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection serviceCollection) {
        // (...)

        serviceCollection.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseOptions)));

        // invalid configuration values will break at this point
        serviceCollection.PostConfigure<DatabaseOptions>(Validation.ValidateDataAnotations);
    }
```

Comment: that's really nice, I posted another solution :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545395/7764329

Answer (score 2):

**Please have a look at the comments since my solution is already available!**

---

Based on [Rodrigo Rodrigues answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545059/7764329) I created my own options validator based on data annotations

```
public sealed class OptionsValidator<TOptions> : IValidateOptions<TOptions> where TOptions : class
{
    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, TOptions options)
    {
        ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(options);
        List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool noValidationErrorsOccured = Validator.TryValidateObject(options, validationContext, validationResults, true);
        
        if (noValidationErrorsOccured) {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
        }
        
        IEnumerable<string> validationFailures = validationResults.Select(validationResult => validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        
        return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validationFailures);
    }
}
```

So whenever I want to add a validator to my DI container I can make use of this extension method

```
public static IServiceCollection AddOptionsValidator<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) where TOptions : class
    => serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<TOptions>, OptionsValidator<TOptions>>();
```

Comment: Note that this is essentially what ValidateDataAnnotations does. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 sorry, I thought this was a custom implementation. How would I use this inside my validator?

Comment: I have a .Net 5 app and wasn't able to find anything like that, where do I have to call it? I looked for it in the DI service registration but also as a static method from a static helper

Comment: You need the DataAnnotations package and you call it on an OptionsBuilder. There are examples in the links from the answer I linked on your OP. But if you check the official docs, about halfway through the heading title "options validation" they show exactly how to use the DataAnnotations package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-validation-1. You don't need your own validator, you just use theirs.

Comment: ah, very cool. So everything remains the same but instead of calling `serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>, OptionsValidator<MyOptions>>()` I can call `serviceCollection.AddOptions<MyOptions>().ValidateDataAnnotations()` ?

Comment: I tested it this way by just changing these lines and it seems to work fine. Just wanted to ask if this is correct :)

Comment: Yah that's correct. The AddOptions part is a bit annoying, but there's ways to make it so you only need to do that once and can piggy back other types by adding the open interface. I know there's examples around somewhere.

Comment: sorry, which things are annoying? This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544514/how-to-trigger-model-validation-inside-ivalidateoptionst-implementation/67545395?noredirect=1#comment119393276_67545395 works fine to me :S

Comment: I was saying needing to call AddOptions in order to call AddDataAnnotations instead of calling it on the Service Collection is the only downside to the built in way of doing this