# How can I check for a missing configuration section when using the Options pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a simple controller that reads some configuration from `appsettings.json` using the Options pattern. It works fine as long as `appsettings.json` is configured correctly. However, what if my configuration section is missing from `appsettings.json`? I hoped to get an `Exception` or `null`, but instead I get a `MySettings` object with default values (i.e. `MyProperty` is `null`).

#### MyController.cs

```cs
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly string value;

    public MyController(IOptions<MySettings> options)
    {
        // Can I validate the `options` object here?
        this.value = options.Value.MyProperty;
    }

    [HttpGet("api/data")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetValue()
    {
        return this.Ok(this.value);
    }
}
```

#### MySettings.cs

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

#### Startup.cs (only showing relevant code)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Tried this:
        services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));

        // Tried this too:
        services.Configure<MySettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Bind(options));
    }
}
```

#### appsettings.json

```json
{
  "MySettings": {
    "MyProperty": "hello world"
  }
}
```

Comment: And what do you want to validate?

Comment: I want to make sure (1) the `MySettings` section is present in `appsettings.json` and (2) all properties are set in that section.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce it in the following way:

1. Add data annotation to your model

```
public class MySettings
{
    [Required]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

2. Call `ValidateDataAnnotations` after `Bind` call

```
services
   .Configure<MySettings>(options => Configuration
     .GetSection("MySettings")
     .Bind(options))
     .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

3. Wrap the property access in a try catch where you except `OptionsValidationException`

```
try
{
   this.value = options.Value.MyProperty;
}
catch(OptionsValidationException ex)
{
   //handle the validation exception
}
```

Comment: This solution works after changing #2 to: `services.AddOptions<MySettings>().Bind(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings")).ValidateDataAnnotations();`

Comment: @srk Yes you are right, let me amend my post.

Answer (score 1):

I found one possible solution on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025264).

Add an extensions method to validate:

```cs
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static T GetValid<T>(this IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var config = configuration.Get<T>();

        try
        {
            Validator.ValidateObject(config, new ValidationContext(config), true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Invalid Configuration", e);
        }

        return config;
    }
}
```

Use that extension method to validate & register the instance in Startup.cs:

```cs
var settings = Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").GetValid<MySettings>();
services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

Change the controller constructor to accept the `MySettings` object directly (instead of `IOptions<MySettings>`):

```cs
public MyController(MySettings options)
{
    this.value = options.MyProperty;
}
```

Another nice consequence of this approach is it removes our dependency on `IOptions` which simplifies the controller a bit.